# ASP.NET MVC Session Timeout doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, session-timeout

If I am seting Session Timeout like less then 20 mins everything is working fine.

But if it is  > 20 mins it doesnt work. It happens with VS 2013 and Production IIS.

Here is a code I have use.

How to fix that issue? Thank you!

**STARTUP.AUTH**

```
  public partial class Startup
    {  
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var sessionTimeout = 5;

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionTimeout),
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
}
```

**GLOBAL.ASAX**

```
 protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Session.Timeout = 5;

        }
```

**P.S. WEB.CONFIG**

```
   <sessionState mode="InProc"  />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" defaultUrl="~/Account/Login" name="MyApp123"   />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: Have you tried using ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0)

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means.  There is no timeout?  It still times out at 20 mintues?  There's no session at all?  How are you measuring that it's timing out?  FYI, Authentication timeout is not Session Timeout, they are two different things.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Look, I set timeout 10 hours via my code. But it expires after 20 minutes. That's the issue.

Comment: Could you expand upon what 'doesn't work' means?  It could be that if you are the only one on the site you are hitting a different timeout such as IIS Idle timeout which has a default of 20 minutes (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx), although this would only be an issue for InProc session.

Comment: @DavidMartin Probably it is. But what is a solution then?

Comment: You could store your session in SQL Database or increase the Idle timeout of IIS.  I would suggest that a session database would be a better approach as you shouldn't really rely upon InProc, especially if you want a session to last 10 hours.

Comment: @DavidMartin - the OP seems to be confusing authentication timeout with session timeout

Comment: @ClarkKent - and how do you know "it expires"?  How are you measuring that?  As I said, Authentication and session are two different things.  The code above is confusing the two.  Which are you actually trying to set?  And which are you actually measuring?  Are you just trying to make sure the users authentication is valid for 10 hours?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch hahahaah :) I am just waiting for 30 mins. :) And it  expires and redirect me to the login page.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I see what you are saying, but to my mind the OP is trying to set both Auth and Session to be the same, which I guess is reasonable, although that intention is not clear from the code, so I'm only guessing.

Comment: @DavidMartin Thanks! I am gonna check the Idle timeout of IIS. If it works I will let you know and would like you to put your answer.

Comment: @ClarkKent - Session has absolutely nothing to do with redirecting you to the login page, unless you have written code which looks at the session and does a redirect.  If you're using the Native security (ie `[Authorize]` or `AuthorizationFilter`, then this is based solely on the the CookieAuthentication timeout regardless of session timeout, or IIS timeouts.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Well... May be you are right... Could you suggest something then and share it like an answer, please?

Comment: @ClarkKent - my point is that if you're setting the ExpireTimeSpan value to something like 10 hours, and you still get redirected, then you need to look at other parts of your code to see if you are doing any redirects based on session or some other expiration value.  This is the only setting that should matter, and if it's still doing it.. then something else must be wrong... you can also try clearing your cookies, since sometimes an old cookie can also confuse things.

Comment: @ClarkKent - also, make sure that you don't still have vestiges of the old FormsAuthentication in your web.config.  You should be removing that module if using asp.net identity (which you seem to be using based on the CookieAuthenticationOptions)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Please take a look at my updated question. I put settings for web.config over there. You are saying that I have to delete this block at all?

Comment: @ClarkKent - If you're using ASP.NET Identity, you should have Authentication mode="None", and you should have a remove statement in the modules to remove FormsAuthentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have FormsAuthentication configuration still in your web.config.  You're using ASP.NET Identity, which conflicts with the old FormsAuthentication.

Change to this:

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
```

And make sure you have this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

You can also just generate a default Web project with asp.net identity, and look at the web.config, which will have the same entries.  Note that the V1 Identity template had a typo that used "FormsAuthenticationModule" instead of "FormsAuthentication" in the remove element.  If you're using v2 or better they fixed that typo.